# How can I remove the password prompt from the lock screen?

Tags: security, greeter

I have enabled Auto Login in the settings. But if the laptop goes inactive, the screen get locked and wants to know the password.

Is there a solution to deactivate the password query on the lock screen if the Auto Login is active?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can deactivate the password query in `System Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Locking`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I feel like an idiot not to have checked the security settings!